# Compare object with an array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've an object and the array as shown below and I wanted to remove all the properties of the object except those listed in the array. Can someone help me with a good lodash function to do this.

```
object : {A:1,B:2,C:3,D:4} 
array: [{type:B,value:xyz,order:1},{type:D,value:abc,order:0}]

I want the object to be {B:2,D:4} after the operation
```

Comment: Can be it done in pure js?

Comment: @Kinduser, thanks for the response. I know how to do it in pure js, but I'm looking for a solution using lodash as we've been using that in our project and wanted to learn the same.

Comment: do you want to mutate the object, or just filter it, or does it not matter?

Comment: @orion, I want to mutate the object, so that the object contains only the fields that are present in array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) like this:

```
var result = _.pick(object, array);
```

```js
var object = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3,
  D: 4
};

var array = ["B", "D"];

var result = _.pick(object, array);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

You should first use [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to get the keys and then use `_.pick` like this:

```
var result = _.pick(object, _.map(array, function(e) {
  return e.type;
}));
```

or using **arrow functions** like this:

```
var result = _.pick(object, _.map(array, e => e.type));
```

or even shorter using the `iteratee` argument like this:

```
var result = _.pick(object, _.map(array, "type"));
```

```js
var object = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3,
  D: 4
};

var array = [{type: "B", value: "xyz", order: 1}, {type: "D", value: "abc", order: 0}];

var result = _.pick(object, _.map(array, "type"));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi, ibrahim thanks for the answer. First of all my apologies, I missed the crucial part of my array at least I believe which I've modified now. I realized about that mistake in my question only after looking at your answer as I've already read about pick before posting my question.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth see the **EDIT** section above!

Comment: Thanks ibrahim. This is what I wanted.

Comment: you can shorten this with `var result = _.pick(object, _.map(array, 'type'));`

Comment: @ryeballar yeah even clearer, didn't know you can do that so thanks!

Comment: @AjaySrikanth See the last edit it's even shorter thanks to ryballar!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.assign()`, `Array.prototype.map()` , spread element, computed property, to assign result of filtering `type` properties to `object`

```js
var object = {A:1,B:2,C:3,D:4} 
var array = [{type:"B",value:"xyz",order:1},{type:"D",value:"abc",order:0}];
object = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(({type}) => ({[type]:object[type]})));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: what is the ... in Object.assign() ? Could you please explain that syntax. I've just started as full time js developer. I'm having trouble understanding few syntax here and there.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth See [What is SpreadElement in ECMAScript documentation? Is it the same as Spread operator at MDN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.pick` along with `_.map` to achieve this:

```
let obj = { A:1, B:2, C:3, D:4 };
let arr = [{ type:'B', value:'xyz', order:1 },{ type:'D', value:'abc', order:0 }];

let output = _.pick(obj, _.map(arr, 'type'));

console.log(output); // { B:2, D: 4 }
```

Example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se23y9gw/)

#### Lodash Docs:

**_.map()**: [link](https://lodash.com/docs/#map)

**_.pick()**: [link](https://lodash.com/docs/#link)

Comment: Check the desired output again!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Ah pants! :-)